# Keyframe animating border-bottom color

Tags: css

I've read over other questions/answers that address keyframes (as well as articles online) and it really seems to me my code should work...but nothing happens. I'm not using any vendor prefixes because from caniuse it seems they aren't necessary anymore.
`

```
@keyframe colorWash {
  from{border-bottom:25px solid #111;}
  50%{border-bottom: 25px solid #333;}
  to{border-bottom:25px solid #777;}
}

#bro {
  padding:2rem;
  background-color:#999;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #111;
  animation: colorWash 10s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for one minor detail (which, in CSS, matters) your animation works:

- it's not `@keyframe`, but `@keyframes`

Now, since you specified it should loop infinitely, I assume you want it smooth. Therefore, you probably want to match `from` with `to` (so the transition between end and start is seamless. I also shortened the duration, so it's easier to observe.

It's also advisable to only specify the property to be animated in `@keyframes`. In your case, `border-bottom-color`:

```css
@keyframes colorWash {
  from {border-bottom-color: #111;}
  42%{border-bottom-color: #777;}
  to {border-bottom-color: #111;}
}

#bro {
  padding:2rem;
  background-color:#999;
  border-bottom: 25px solid;
  animation: colorWash 3s infinite;
  }
```

```html
<div id="bro"></div>
```

Comment: ermagerd lol about keyframe vs keyframes. Thanks for the help and I appreciate the other tips b/c I didn't know those either!